# Context vs. Selector specificy in jQuery

Tags: jquery

There are times when one can specify the scope in which a particular element might be found either by using a hierarchical selector, ie:

```
$('#someParent .someChildren')
```

...or by using context, ie:

```
$('.someChildren', $('#someParent'))
```

I know there are times when one can't use the former, so obviously the latter is useful.  But in situations like the one I present, which is better and why?

Comment: Which context do you present? No context? Like, which is better overall?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Do you mean in my first example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
$('.someChildren', $('#someParent'))
```

is simply converted into this:

```
$('#someParent').find('.someChildren')
```

after running some tests. So the actual consideration will be between:

```
$('#someParent .someChildren')
```

and:

```
$('#someParent').find('.someChildren')
```

*(taking into consideration the work of analyzing and converting).*

So which of those two is faster will likely be browser dependent. I personally never use the `context` parameter.

If you want a `.find()`, then I'd just use it directly instead of having jQuery flip it for you.

People often use the `context` when the need to set `this` as the root of the `.find()`.

```
$('.someChildren', this)
```

...so in that case, it is faster to do this:

```
$(this).find('.someChildren')
```

...and more easily understandable in my opinion.

Comment: So, is it your opinion that the context parameter is completely useless?

Comment: @Justin: I believe there are (or were) some special uses for it with `.live()`. Aside from that, I see no reason to use it in place of `.find()` except personal preference. [Here's where jQuery does the flip.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.5.1/src/core.js#L162-166)

Comment: @Justin: Yes, but that doesn't change the fact that jQuery is simply turning `$(selector, context)` into `$(context).find(selector)` and starting over. In the example you gave, it will be a question of using a full selector vs an ID find selector. The performance will vary based on selectors and browser. It could be that `.find()` is faster in some situations.

Comment: Yup, it seems you are absolutely right.  Nonetheless, it's still useful with .delegate(), right?  Or can I chain .find() to .delegate() and still have it bind to newly emergent elements?

Comment: @Justin: `.delegate()` doesn't bind new elements. It places a single handler on the container, and processes events when they bubble up to it. No future binding is performed with `.delegate()` or `.live()`. They both use "event delegation".

Comment: Gotcha.  OK, so my only outstanding question is:  is .find() faster than using a more specific selector?  You say it's browser-dependent.  Do you have a sense of which is generally better on popular browsers?

Comment: @JustinMylesHolmes that's micro optimising ;) You shouldn't care about it unless you find a bottleneck.

Comment: @Justin The single selector will probably be fastest in all modern browsers, since it can use the native function `querySelectorAll` rather than running (comparatively slow) Javascript.

Comment: @Justin: Browsers that support the native `querySelectorAll` will likely have comparable performance either way. That includes pretty much every browser except IE6/IE7. There's a popular question somewhere here on SO that has an answer that supposedly proves that `$('#anId').find('.aChild')` is way faster than `$('#anId .aChild')`. The trouble is that the test to prove it uses an immensely long and complex page, that also has some invalid HTML outside of the targeted ID range. Given a more normal situation, I'd guess that the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 2):

```
    // HANDLE: $(expr, $(...))
} else if (!context || context.jquery) {
    return (context || rootjQuery).find(selector);
    // HANDLE: $(expr, context)
    // (which is just equivalent to: $(context).find(expr)
} else {
    return this.constructor(context).find(selector);
}
```

From the [source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.5&fn=jQuery.fn.init)

here we can see that using

`$("#foo .bar")` reduces to `$(document).find("#foo .bar")`

`$(".bar", $("#foo"))` reduces to `$("#foo").find(".bar")`

It's hard to tell which is more efficient. Either sizzle is slow with that descendent selector or having to call `$(..)` twice is slower. This does indeed require benchmarking. Also note that `$(document)` is cached as `rootjQuery`

As @patrick_dw mentioned it's probably better to compare it to `$("#foo").find(".bar")` directly instead.