# Performance of jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

HTML markup:

```
<div>

 <a id="foo"> </a>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('div').each(function(){

 $('#foo', this).dosmth(); // 1
 $('#foo').dosmth();       // 2

});
```

Which method would be faster to run `dosmth`?

Comment: Probably worth asking, but why are you iterating through divs seeing if they contain an object with a particular ID? There should only be one ID of `"foo"` in the DOM.

Answer (score 4):

Since we're getting a variety of answers, hopefully here's some clarity ([check the examples here](http://jsfiddle.net/brymck/tr4fz/)):

1. **The fastest** - There's no need to loop. Skip the `$("div").each` part and just do `$("#foo")`. `foo` is an ID, and thus lookup is instantaneous.
2. **Middling** - `$("#foo")` in a loop. Note that you also don't want this because it will execute the function for every div on the page (and for this reason on a larger document with a lot of divs this would be the slowest).
3. **Slowest** - `$("#foo", this)`. The context node doesn't help in the first place, and then consider that jQuery will first build a jQuery object out of `this` and turn it into `$(this).find("#foo")`. That's all unnecessary, of course.

Bottom line: in most cases (e.g. sometimes when confirming that an ID is in one context and not another) context nodes are unnecessary with ID lookup.

Here are some resources from the jQuery source:

- [Handling for most of the cases here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L115-174) - note that `$("#id")` is singled out for handling as `document.getElementById`
- [`find`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L19-54) - what happens when you pass a context

Comment: I updated your fiddle to add also a document.getElementById('foo'). http://jsfiddle.net/tr4fz/4/ It's not a jQuery selector, but it's worth reminding that whenever possible that is the fastest way to retrieve an element by ID.

Answer (score 2):

Since an `#id` should be unique in the DOM your markup will be invalid (I am assuming more than one `<div/>` based upon using `.each()`)

Change the id to a class and use the following:

```
<div>
 <a class="foo"> </a>
</div>
<div>
 <a class="foo"> </a>
</div>
```

And the script

```
$('div').each(function(){
   $('.foo', this).dosmth(); //or $(this).find(".foo");
});
```

But if you only have ***one*** element with an id of `foo` selecting by id will be the fastest, plus you can drop the need for using `.each()`

```
$('#foo').dosmth(); //or document.getElementById("foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery selectors by id only is the fastest way to search because it uses getElementbyId in javascript.

so this one is the fastest:

```
$('#foo').dosmth();
```

if you use a context like:

```
$('#foo', this).dosmth();
```

it is translated into:

```
$(this).find('#foo').dosmth();
```

so that will make another useless operation because your #foo is unique

Regards,

Max

Answer (score 0):

***Please read the discussion below regarding this answer or check Bryan answer above about the differences in speed of the selectors.***

> I would go with
>
> ```
>    $('a#foo', this).dosmth();
> ```
>
> **Update** But instead of retrieving all the divs before, I would check for
>   only the desired one at the first time
>   like this
>
> ```
> $('div a#foo').each(function(){
> }
> ```

Comment: @Jose I don't believe it's faster because from javascript's side the fastest way is `document.getElementById('foo')`. I don't know how is jQuery implemented, but believe it's logical to think that they use getElementById in this case. I even think that FIRST method is slower because jquery needs to test for `this` context.

Comment: Totally agree with you, and yes, jQuery internally uses getElementById(), but we are talking about jQuery selectors here... ;)

Comment: @Jose The question was about the performance of this particular case. So I think `$('#foo').dosmth();` is the fastest way :) But I haven't tested. It's just my considerations.

Comment: Judging from the jQuery [source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js) (1.6.1, first match on `getElementById()`), only a `#ID` selection will be handled directly by `getElementById()`. `tag#ID` will not. Neither will `#ID` with a `context`. (The expression to match is `/^(?:[^<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|#([\w\-]*)$)/` where `getElementById()` is used if both `match[1]` and `context` are falsy. I.e., it *must* match `^#([\w\-]*)$` and be without `context`.)

Comment: There's been another question recently about the subject here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184535/context-vs-selector-specificy-in-jquery

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first way is among the slower lookups. Instead of doing a straight `document.getElementById` -- which is exactly what jQuery does when it sees `$("#foo")` -- your method builds a jQuery object out of `this`, then runs `$(this).find("a#foo")`, which will then search for `<a>` tags in `$(this)`, and then search through those `<a>` tags with `getElementById`.

Comment: Now that makes things clear... I would like to preserve this comment discussion cause I think it may be useful, but would like to throw lines in my answer cause now I see it's wrong. Could it be done or should I delete the answer entirely?

Comment: I think it's better to either revise the answer or just direct readers to the discussion. I think the comments are pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foo', this).dosmth();
```

This will search within the context of the `div` and not the whole DOM, which will make the selector faster. This only makes sense to use when the DOM is large, otherwise, just use the normal selector: `$('#foo').dosmth();`

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using an id there's only ever going to be one. So you can just do:

   $('a#foo').dosmth();
2. You don't need to use each() to go through each div and get all the a#foo's out of it. That WILL waste time, creating loops for no reason. Instead use:

   $('a#foo').each(function(){ ... });

or even just:

```
$('a#foo').dosmth();
```

You can also do `$('div a#foo').dosmth();` if you want.